# openmaptiles-server didn't work by using docker

Tags: docker, openmaptiles

I use docker to install openmaptiles-server
command `docker pull klokantech/openmaptiles-server`.
It starts downloading and extracting.

Everything looks fine.

I use command `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8088:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server` to start OSM and open my Browser visit ip:8088.

It shows me "Existing MBTiles were found in the /data volume. The following file will be used:2017-07-03_china_beijing.mbtiles" , I click "continue" and "OPEN MAP SERVER" . IT REFUSE CONNECTION.
I don't know whether I miss something or some process I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this command (docker on windows) ?

```
docker run -it -v //c/Docker:/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl
```